# Book about a magician's apprentice who gets stuck in a painting

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic

I am trying to remember the title of a book about a boy who learns magic.

It was so long ago all I can remember is:

- A young boy is being taught magic.
- He goes on an adventure.
- He gets stuck in a painting.
- In the painting is a powerful book of magic which he begins to study.
- He finds out how to get out of the painting.
- On his way back to his village, he somehow is travelling in a flying castle and pays back a man that he borrowed or stole a boat from during his journey.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is Lawrence Watt-Evans's *[With a Single Spell](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/320216.With_a_Single_Spell)*

> Tobas had been lucky to find a wizard to take him on as apprentice. But then the wizard died suddenly and unexpectedly after teaching Tobas only a solitary spell, and the youth was too old to find a new master. How could he earn a living when all the magic he could do was light fires?
>
> A DESTINY UNFOLDING
>
> In the Small Kingdoms there were dragons to be slain, princesses and gold to be won, magic castles, witches who knew the secret of immortality, and other treasures. But how could a wizard with a single, simple spell hope to find them and win them?

Tobas travels through a magic tapestry to a wizard's castle. Indeed, he finds a book of powerful spells from the prior owner, as well as the wizard's immortal wife. They are trapped because the return portrait is no longer accurate, but Tobas finds a way to fix that. And yes, at the end, Tobas tracks down the person whose boat he stole and gives them a replacement.

Comment: FWIW, it's the last detail that made me recognize this, although I had an inkling when you mentioned he was trapped in a painting.

Comment: haha thank you so much I can't wait to read it again , it's the book that got me into fantasy and really ignited a desire to read for enjoyment